# Export Filtered Rows from Access Datasheet to Excel

Tags: excel, ms-access, datasheet

I'm using the VBA code below to export just the visible columns in an Access Datasheet to Excel. Works great, but I also want to export only the filtered rows, based on what the user has filtered for each column.
i could use some help figureing out how to do that.
Any help is appreciated,
lq

```
 Public Function ExportToExcel()
 On Error GoTo myErr

     Dim strDestFolder As String
     Dim strSQL As String
     Dim qdf As dao.QueryDef
     Dim ctl As Control
     Dim strRandomString As String

     strDestFolder = "MyDestinationPath"
     strRandomString = "AQueryDefName"

     For Each ctl In Me.Child.Form.Controls

         If Not ctl.ColumnHidden Then
             If Len(strSQL) = 0 Then
                 strSQL = "SELECT " & ctl.ControlSource & ", "
             Else
                 strSQL = strSQL & ctl.ControlSource & ", "
             End If
         End If

     Next ctl

     If Len(strSQL) > 0 Then
         strSQL = Left(strSQL, Len(strSQL) - 2)
         strSQL = strSQL & " FROM tblMyTableName WHERE Something = '" & Me.Something & "'"
     End If

     Set qdf = CurrentDb.CreateQueryDef(strRandomString, strSQL)

     DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputQuery, strRandomString, "MicrosoftExcel (*.xls)", strDestFolder & ".xls", True

 myExit:
     CurrentDb.QueryDefs.Delete strRandomString
     Exit Function
 myErr:
     MsgBox Err.Number & " - " & Err.Description, vbCritical, "VBA Error"
     Resume myExit
 End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

The filter property of the subform should return a line suitable for use in a where statement. For example:

```
([My subform].[ID] Not In (1,2,4,6))
```

Is returned when I select the dropdown and choose some numbers. Also:

```
([My subform].[ID] In (719,720))
```